# Buscar archivos por extensión, por nombre inicial y evaluar contenido de arraylist

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
private void buscarArchivo(File ruta, String nomArchivo) {
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
        File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
        if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
            for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
                File Arc = archivo[i];
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                    buscarArchivo(archivo[i], nomArchivo);
                } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extencion. 
                    if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".docx")) {
                        contador++;
                        ArrayArchivos.add(archivo[i].getName());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

El cual lo utilizo para buscar en una direccion especifica y evaluo la extensión de dichos archivos los cuales se agregan a un arraylist, pero lo que necesito saber es:

- Como evaluar por búsqueda de nombre, un carácter especifico, por ej:que cumplan el formato `PD??_?????????.PND` donde `?` serian caracteres sin importancia, es decir, necesito filtrar los archivos que empiecen con PD seguido de dos num + _ + otros num de 9 digitos+ su extensión `.pnd` . Los valores de los digitos numericos no son de importancia, lo importante es que me agregue al array los que cumplan el patron indicado.
- Una vez evaluado lo anterior evaluar su extension, lo cual ya hago en mi codigo e agregar al array dicho filtro.
- Evaluar el contenido del arraylist, por ej: saber si existe las extensiones `.pnd` o `.ana` o `.cnf` que no haga nada. Pero si existe solo archivos `.pnd` sin la existencia de las otras extenciones que haga otra cosa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Como evaluar por búsqueda de nombre, un carácter especifico, por
>   ej:que cumplan el formato  PD??_?????????.PND donde ? serian
>   caracteres sin importancia, es decir, necesito filtrar los archivos
>   que empiecen con PD seguido de dos num + _ + otros num de 9 digitos+
>   su extensión .pnd

Puedes utilizar una expresión regular para determinar si el nombre del archivo cumple con ese patrón, ,mediante las clases [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) y [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Una instancia de la clase `Pattern` es una representación de una expresión regular. El patrón puede ser utilizado para crear un `Matcher` el cual puede comparar un conjunto de caracteres con una expresión regular.

Puedes definir un método que determine si el nombre del archivo cumple con:

- Comienza con "PD"
- Seguido de dos dígitos, el caracter "_" y nueve dígitos.
- finaliza con el caracter "." y "PND" o "pnd"

**La expresión regular a utilizar:**

```
^PD[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{9}.(PND|pnd)$
```

- `^`: inicio del string
- `PD`: El literal "PD"
- `[0-9]{2}`: únicamente 2 dígitos
- `_`: el caracter "_"
- `[0-9]{9}`: únicamente 9 dígitos
- `.` : el caracter "."
- `(PND|pnd)`: el literal "PND" o el literal "pnd"
- `$`: fin del string

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fynkJUnJ6V_LVIev)

**Implementación en Java:**

```
private boolean checkFileName(String fileName){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^PD[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{9}.(PND|pnd)$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(fileName);
        return m.matches();
}

System.out.println(checkFileName("PD23_123456789.PND")); // true
System.out.println(checkFileName("PD213_123456789.pnd")); // false
System.out.println(checkFileName("PD23_12345789.pnd")); // false
System.out.println(checkFileName("PD11_111111111.pnd")); // true
```

> Evaluar el contenido del arraylist, por ej: saber si existe las extensiones .pnd o .ana o .cnf que no haga nada. Pero si existe solo archivos .pnd sin la existencia de las otras extenciones que haga otra cosa.

Este control lo puedes durante la ejecución de `buscarArchivo()`, sin necesidad de recorrer el array. Por ejemplo, definiendo un booleano que determine si todos tus archivos son de extensión `.pnd` y si en la búsqueda encuentras uno que no cumpla esa condición alterar ese valor y en función del mismo determinar con que acciones continuar.

```
private boolean existsOnlyPndFiles = true;

private void buscarArchivo(File ruta, String nomArchivo) {
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
        File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
        if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
            for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
                File Arc = archivo[i];
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                    buscarArchivo(archivo[i], nomArchivo);
                } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extencion. 

                    if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".docx")) {
                        if(!archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd")){
                            // Si no termina con .pnd implica que no todos los archivos son de esa extensión
                             existsOnlyPndFiles = false;
                         }
                        contador++;
                        ArrayArchivos.add(archivo[i].getName());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```